# joomla | gallery that show different text for each image

Tags: gallery, joomla3.0, image-gallery

In my website there are different pages, in each page there is a gallery created by "Simple Image Gallery", but I need to show a different html table for each image after clicking on thumbnail! Do you know a gallery that allows that?

Comment: you mean different joomla plugin

Comment: Yes, I could use a different plugin if it allows what I need

Answer (score 0):

Try joomgallery which has very good features with translation support.

http://www.en.joomgallery.net/downloads/joomgallery-for-joomla-3.html